get values of aggregation MUI - Datagrid
I’m facing an issue with aggregation in a custom export where I need to retrieve the aggregated values from the table, but I’m unsure how to access them.
V 6.20.4.
I tried using gridAggregationLookupSelector, which is the closest solution I’ve found so far, but the returned object has the following structure:
{
  "auto-generated-group-node-root": {
    "AGE": {
      "position": "footer",
      "value": 12
    }
  }
}

I'm uncertain if I should be accessing the auto-generated-group-node-root property directly.
